# Cylindrical surface with maximum area?

Tags: variational-analysis

Imagine we have a parametic surface given by:
$$
\Phi(r, \theta) = \begin{pmatrix} 
r \cos{\theta} \\
r \sin{\theta} \\
f(r) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
r \in \mathbb R^+, \; \; \; \ \theta \in [0, 2\pi]
$$
$f$, will only depend on $r$, for simplicity.

Finding the tangent vectors to the surfaces:
$$
\vec r = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos{\theta} \\
\sin{\theta} \\
f'(r) \\
\end{pmatrix} \; \; \; \;
\vec\theta = \begin{pmatrix} 
-r\sin{\theta} \\
r \cos{\theta} \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$
d\vec{S} = ||\vec r \times\vec\theta|| \; dr d\theta  = \sqrt { r^2 + f'(r)^2} \; dr d\theta \\
$$
$$
S = \iint_{\Omega} {\sqrt { r^2 + f'(r)^2} \; dr d\theta}
$$
Using Euler-Lagrange Equations to find the extrema of the functional:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{d r}\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial f'} = 0
$$
We have:
$$
f'(r) = r \\
rf''(r) = f'(r)
$$
Solving this two equations gives:
$$
f_1(r) = \frac{1}{2}r^2 + C \\
f_2(r) =  C_1 r^2 + C_2
$$
Does this means that the cylindrical surfaces (without a $\theta$ dependence) which maximizes its area are paraboloids? Is my line of reasoning right? Did I made any mistakes?

Comment: Unfortunately, you made a mistake at the beginning; indeed, one has : 
$$
\|\vec{r}\times\vec{\theta}\| = r\sqrt{1+f'(r)^2} \neq \sqrt{r^2+f'(r)^2}
$$